# Domain of a field depends on another one

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I have a class with a field many2many (`invoice_ids`) whose domain depends on another field (`department_id`). I created an onchange method to return the domain every time the `department_id` field is modified. This works perfectly but when I save the object and try to edit it, the domain does not work because the onchange is not executed. How could I modify my class so that the domain code works also when editing the object without making an onchange of the field `department_id`?

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.class'

    department_id = fields.Many2one('hr.department', string="Department", required=True)
    invoice_ids = fields.Many2many('account.invoice', 'my_class_invoice_rel', 'my_class_id', 'invoice_id', string="Invoices")


    @api.onchange('department_id')
    def onchange_department_id(self):
        if self.department_id:
            some_search_id = self.env['some.model'].search([('department_id', '=', self.department_id.id)])
            return {'domain': {'invoice_ids': [('state', '=', 'open'), ('some_model_id', 'not in', some_search_id), ('partner_id.department_id', 'child_of', self.department_id.id)]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dayana 
Apart from the onchange method you've to go through the compute method. Else I'll show you the exact scenario what you are looking for.

```
class FleetVehicle(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'fleet.vehicle'
emirate_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state', string="Emirate", domain="[('country_id', '=','United Arab Emirates')]")

@api.onchange('emirate_id')
    def onchange_emirate(self):
        self.plate_type_id = False
        if self.emirate_id:
            return {'domain': {'plate_type_id': [('id', 'in', self.emirate_id.plate_type_ids.ids)]}}
        else:
            return {'domain': {'plate_type_id': [('id', '=', False)]}}

class CountryState(models.Model):
    _description = "Country state"
    _inherit = 'res.country.state'

    plate_type_ids = fields.Many2many('vehicle.plate.type', string="Plate Types")
```

Hope you understand this. Thank you !

Don't forget to upvote this and put the tick mark though.